# Electric guitars that can fit Firebird humbuckers with minimal effort

Tags: guitar, electric-guitar, pick-ups

I love the sound of the Seymour Duncan Firebird pickups, but I can't work out what type of guitar I could fit them in without having a massive headache. I'd love to get these into an SG body, but I fear it would be a lot of effort that I'm not equipped for!

Comment: Well, what kind of effort *are* you up for?  Milling out the cavity to fit the pickups is about the only really tough job.  If the pickups fit, there are plenty of ways to bond them in or drill new anchor holes, etc.

Comment: If by *"firebird pickups"* you just mean *"mini humbuckers"*, then you can buy cheap adapter rings for many humbucker-equipped guitars (SGs included).

Comment: @jonrsharpe I think your comment is the answer and should be an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pickups in the classic Gibson Firebird are known as *"mini-humbuckers"*. You can buy adapters to replace the full-size humbucker mounting rings used by many guitars, including most SGs, that will allow a mini-humbucker to be used instead. As this just screws to the top of the guitar in place of the previous ring, it's a reversible operation that won't cause damage.